# Possible to use Ng-repeat with Ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ellipsis

I want to give an effect of ... in my text and I am using angularjs.

Can we use text-overflow: ellipsis;
with ng-repeat to give a tex... effect?

I tried its not working for me. Please suggest!

Code

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap; max-width: 2em; text-overflow: ellipsis; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;" ng-repeat="data in g.k()">
    {{data.name}}
</span>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` is a loop directive, it has nothing to do with how you style the content. Maybe you can explain your use case better?

Comment: updated with code. I hoped it to work, but it is not working!, I am not able to understand why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) only has an effect when the `overflow` property is different from `visible`.

Also, `max-width` does not apply to non-replaced inline elements ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths)), which `span`s are by default. Example working code:

```
.ellipsis {
  max-width: 3em;
  display: inline-block; /*enables max-width and overflow properties*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Now apply the class to the element:

```
<div ng-repeat="your loop directive">
  <span class="ellipsis">{{something}}</span>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/AbAJAXa/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You need block element, not span.
Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BmGc5zQ49WVp7aqFyYLq?p=preview
Also, this property is not most supported by browsers,  so think about using "limitTo" filter also.